# Не могу разобраться с вордом

Tags: c#, com, ms-word

При выполнении кода вылетают 2 ошибки:

Ошибка  1   Нераспознанная управляющая последовательность
Ошибка  2   Элемент "document" не существует в текущем контексте.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    String details = "<<USER NAME>>";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void documentWriter(String data)
   {
    try {
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        //wordApp.Visible = true;
       // WordApp.ShowAnimation = true;

      Object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document writer = WordApp.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        writer.Content.SetRange(0,0);
        writer.Content.Text= data + Environment.NewLine;

        Object filename = "e:\\new.docx";
        writer.SaveAs(ref filename);
        writer.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        writer = null;
        WordApp.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        MessageBox.Show("Document Saved"+ filename.ToString());
}
    catch(Exception e) { MessageBox.Show(""+e); }

   }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       details= "First Name ::" + richTextBox1.Text + "\nLast Name ::" + richTextBox2.Text + "\nCoumtry ::" + richTextBox3.Text +"n\Age ::"+ richTextBox4.Text;

       document.Writer(details);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: 1. На какой строчке ошибка? 2. Где у вас объявлен `document`?

Comment: со второй ошибкой разобрался... последняя строка documentWord без точки)                                                                                                                              на счёт первой ошибки... предпоследняя строка

Comment: Наверное на это ругается: `\A`, у вас там пара символов местами перепутаны

Comment: Андрей... не совсем понял, какие символы перепутаны... я что то вычитал ещё, что там типа нужно поставить двойной слеш.. но успеха не вышло...

Comment: У вас в одном месте вместо `\n` написано `n\A`, отсюда и баг

Comment: ОК... исправил, ошибки исчезли... НО теперь ругается на то что библиотека 12 года а не 14... начал искать, отдельно не вижу откуда скачать(microsoft word 14.0 object library)

Comment: Она должна быть у вас, просто подключите через References, а 12ю отключите. Это не год, это версия

Comment: Нет, у меня нету, если я только чего то не пропустил.... Поэтому каким то образом нужно её добавить... Андрей не могли бы вы сделать чат, чтобы не засорять здесь?

Comment: У вас мало репутации, вам нельзя в чат

Comment: Что нужно сделать чтобы добаваить более новую версию microsoft word 14.0 object library?

Comment: Вроде это: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-install-office-primary-interop-assemblies

Comment: .NET Framework у меня версия 4.5...... выходит нужно поставить версию, которая не старше 2.0?

Comment: Нет, наоборот. Но нужна версия офиса не ниже 2010

Comment: а будет ли код работать на других компах, где версия ворда может быть младше?

Comment: Не знаю, проверяйте, в любом случае нужно за собой таскать библиотеку

Comment: Так библиотека получается в комплекте с Office 2010 или с .NET Framework ниже 2.0?

Comment: Библиотека идёт в комплекте с офисом, опционально при установке. 14 версия это офис 2010.

Comment: Замечательно! Поставил office 2010, библиотеку даже не пришлось устанавливать... ошибки исчезли, но появились 2 предупреждения: Предупреждение 1 Не удалось определить зависимости ссылок COM "VBIDE". Ошибка при загрузке библиотеки. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)) WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: Предупреждение 2 не удается найти сборку-оболочку для библиотеки типов "VBIDE". Убедитесь, что (1) компонент COM правильно зарегистрирован и (2) разрядность целевой платформы совпадает с разрядностью компонента COM. Например, если компонент COM является 32-разрядным, целевая платформа не должна быть 64-разрядной. WindowsFormsApplication1
Теперь вопрос с разрядностью....  office поставил 32-разрядный... источник предупреждений не пойму...

Comment: Немного почитал... что там вроде как можно, нужно сделать компиляцию под 32-разрядной платформой... не вижу как..